# Symfony duplicate Assert possible?

Tags: php, symfony, validation, assert

Could an approach like this work? I would test it but thats for another task...

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Bitte wählen sie eine valide Datei.", groups={"textimage", "video"})
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "video/mp4" }, groups={"video"})
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg" }, groups={"textimage"})
 */
private $media;
```

So I have one media property on the entity which should work for two different types of media - seperated by validation groups.

Would be nice if this would work - anyone knows that?  If not whats the correct approach for that?

Comment: Why not `@Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "video/mp4",  "image/jpeg" }` and ignore group?

Comment: well its a Form were we switch one Part arround with js, one mutation of the form is for img only and the other for vid only - with your Suggestion wouldnt it be possible to submit both vid/img in every submit?

Comment: well, the two asserts work as expected.